# Create a grouped Seaborn Box plot without pandas.melt() or pandas.stack()

Tags: python, pandas, seaborn

I want to create a "grouped box plot" like this without using `pandas.melt()` (or `pandas.stack()`) and with only one seaborn function :

[image]

In my "environment" I often have data in a "wide" structure like this.

```
|    |   ID |   catA |   catB |
|---:|-----:|-------:|-------:|
|  0 |    0 |    168 |    181 |
|  1 |    1 |    151 |    100 |
|  2 |    2 |     84 |     56 |
|  3 |    3 |     51 |    151 |
|  4 |    4 |    102 |    123 |
|  5 |    5 |     80 |     50 |
|  6 |    6 |    156 |    181 |
|  7 |    7 |     60 |    196 |
|  8 |    8 |     95 |    162 |
|  9 |    9 |    116 |    180 |
```

To create a boxplot for the two columns `catA` and `catB` I usally melt/stack them.

```
df = df.melt('ID', var_name='cat', value_name='val')
seaborn.boxplot(x=df.val, y=df.cat).figure.show()
```

Does seaborn do offer a way to get to the same result without explicit using `melt()` or something else transforming the original dataframe? Like this seaborn pseudo code.

```
seaborn.boxplot(x=[df.catA, df.catB]).figure.show()
```

Here is the MWE to produce the data frame.

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3
import random
import pandas
import seaborn

random.seed(0)

k = 10
df = pandas.DataFrame(
    {
        'ID': range(k),
        'catA': random.choices(range(200), k=k),
        'catB': random.choices(range(200), k=k)
    }
)
```

Result

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do:

```
sns.boxplot(data=df.drop(columns='ID'), orient='h').figure.show()
```

You can also select columns rather than to drop useless columns:

```
sns.boxplot(data=df[['catA', 'catB']], orient='h').figure.show()
```

Output:

[image]

Comment: If I would had an additional column `gender` how would I do something like `y="gender"` or `hue="gender"`? This parameters not working when using `data=`.

Comment: It's not possible, you have to reshape your dataframe. The documentation for `data` is *data: Dataset for plotting. If x and y are absent, this is interpreted as wide-form. Otherwise it is expected to be long-form.*